# ListView Click and LongClick

Tags: java, android

I have a ListView with an ItemClickListener and an ItemLongClickListener. When you click an item, it starts a new activity. When you long click an item, it sets the visibility of a hidden textview in that row to visible.

When you long click, the hidden textview becomes visible, but when you release the click it starts the new activity, which I don't want.

How do I go about having both listeners? Also, I'm considering on a long click to make the hidden textview visible in all rows (using LongClickListener instead of ItemLongClickListener), not just the clicked one but I'm unable to get it to even recognize a longclick then.

Comment: are you returning `true` after done processing `ItemLongClickListener()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return `true` to signalize that the event has been handled.